# MySQL query optimization for joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables which I need to perform a left outer join on to get the result set I want. The query I have now works but its taking too long to process. Any suggestions?

Query:

```
SELECT Date_format(a.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') Call_Date,
   Date_format(a.call_date, '%H:%i:%s') Call_Time,
   a.lead_id,
   customer_number,
   status,
   a.call_type,
   agent,
   skill,
   campaign,
   disposition,
   hangup,
   a.uniqueid,
   time_to_answer,
   talk_time,
   hold_sec,
   wrapup_sec,
   Date_format(start_time, '%H:%i:%s')  Start_Time,
   Date_format(end_time, '%H:%i:%s')    End_Time,
   Ifnull(a.transfered, b.transfered)   AS transfer,
   comments,
   location,
   duration,
   handling_time,
   number_dialed                        AS DID
FROM   cdr_temp a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT USER,
                           Substring(number_dialed, 18, 11) AS transfered,
                           uniqueid
                    FROM   transfertable)
                   b
                ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE  a.call_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-23 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY a.lead_id,
      b.uniqueid
```

Tables:cdr_temp
[image: cdr_temp]

transfertable
[image: transfertable]

Index:

```
uniqueid and call_date for transfertable
uniqueid and lead_id for cdr_temp
```

Explain on query

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1333    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  transfertable   ref     uniqueid    uniqueid    22  test.a.uniqueid     1
```

PS: I need to concatenate skills and number_dialed on GROUP BY. I've tried using GROUP_CONCAT but it didn't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: a join on a select is always going to take ages, try a view or rethinking the data structure. at least it seems all your "wheres" are indexed.

Comment: the tables and its data are generated by another program, i only have access to reading the data so I'll try with view.

Comment: Never include a GROUP BY clause in a query devoid of any aggregating functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point of the subquery on the `transfertable`.  But, looking closely at that subquery, I can see that you are calling `SUBSTRING` there.  This almost certainly means that MySQL won't be able to use any index to improve that join.  One approach here would be to create a temporary table containing the substring of the `number_dialed` as a bona-fide column.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE transfertable_temp (
    INDEX idx (uniqueid, transfered)
)
SELECT uniqueid, SUBSTRING(number_dialed, 18, 11) AS transfered
FROM transfertable;
```

Joining to this temporary table (in lieu of a materialized view, which MySQL does not yet support) should improve the performance of the join, should MySQL choose to use it.  Note that I also include the substring number in the index, to cover that other column being used.

Here is your updated query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(a.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') Call_Date,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.call_date, '%H:%i:%s') Call_Time,
    a.lead_id,
    customer_number,
    status,
    a.call_type,
    agent,
    skill,
    campaign,
    disposition,
    hangup,
    a.uniqueid,
    time_to_answer,
    talk_time,
    hold_sec,
    wrapup_sec,
    Date_format(start_time, '%H:%i:%s') Start_Time,
    Date_format(end_time, '%H:%i:%s') End_Time,
    IFNULL(a.transfered, b.transfered) transfer,
    comments,
    location,
    duration,
    handling_time,
    b.number_dialed DID
 FROM cdr_temp a
 LEFT JOIN transfertable_temp b
    ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE
    a.call_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-23 00:00:00';
```

Note: Using `GROUP BY` in your current query makes no sense, especially since you don't even call any aggregate functions.  If you think you have a need for aggregation, then edit your question and tell us why.

Comment: Can't we use a table variable since its faster then and use a unique constraint or does that make it useless in filesorting?

Comment: Not sure about the performance gains of using a table variable.  The main point of my answer is that regular index on the actual table probably won't work, because you are calling substring on one of the columns being used.  A temp table with an index is one possibility.

Comment: I'm using GROUP By just to remove duplicate rows not for aggregation.

Comment: Then your current attempted use of `GROUP BY` makes no sense.  Maybe use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT won't work since I'm removing duplicates based on two columns only and not on the entire columns specified. Hence my option is limited to GROUP BY

Comment: That's fine, but then you need to also provide for _which_ value/row you want to select for each group of those two columns.  You current query, as written, makes no sense.

Comment: Hey Tim, I've finally understood your point and yes I do need an aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT on skills